# Add Indent Guide Line In netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: php, netbeans-7

NetBeans 7.0.1 did not show  indent guide lines (light gray dotted vertical lines). How can I turn that feature on?

Comment: `View > Show Indent Guide Lines.`

Comment: Sorry... i did'nt see any option like this in View